# Override client side certificate authentication validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a web application that does Client Certificate authentication to a 3rd party API. The application is working however I'd like to move it to Azure App Services.

The certificate used for client authentication is not issued from a CA that is the Trusted Root Certificate store. Azure does not allow adding certificates to the Trusted Root Certificate store in App Services, for obvious reasons.

As far as I can tell the default behavior on the client is to not send the client certificate if the trust chain cannot be validated. Is there a way in .net to override this behavior and send the certificate anyway?

I know that [ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback(v=vs.110).aspx) allows you to override checking the Server certificate but doesn nothing for validating the client certificate.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge I think you are on the right track and that using this code:

```
ServicePointManager
.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
(sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

Should actually get you the results you want? As the server will validate the client certificate, throw an error, setting the callback to true will override any errors. I'm unclear as to if you have tried this solution already, sounds like you might have done.

Comment: I've tried this approach. It doesn't seem to apply to sending a client certificate. The issue I have is that even when I add a client certificate to a request it's never actually sent and ServerCertificateValidationCallback is never called.

Comment: Doesn't all of this negate the point of using certificates? If you are just accepting any certificate regardless of validity why use client certs at all?

Comment: I agree @SimonW, however if you don't have the root CA (limited scenarios I know) then it could still be valid or if you are using self-signed certificates. Personally though I would always try and accept certificates properly.

Comment: I'd like to be able to perform my own validation on the root CA as Azure won't let me put in my own root CA in the trusted root store.